# Autofixture strange error

Tags: .net, autofixture

I'm getting this error.

> Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.IllegalRequestException
>   : A request for an IntPtr was
>   detected. This is an unsafe resource
>   that will crash the process if used,
>   so the request is denied. A common
>   source of IntPtr requests are requests
>   for delegates such as Func or
>   Action. If this is the case, the
>   expected workaround is to Customize
>   (Register or Inject) the offending
>   type by specifying a proper creational
>   strategy.

This is my test code.I'm using autofac and one of the dependencies is an aggregate service.

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var moq = new Mock<ITaskReadService>();
moq.Setup(x => x.GetFormItems(1)).Returns(GetDataTable());

IIcpServiceAggregate aggregate = _container.Resolve<IIcpServiceAggregate>();

fixture.Freeze(aggregate);
fixture.Freeze(moq.Object);

var c = fixture.CreateAnonymous<TaskController>();
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that TaskController is an ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller, you should be able to fix this particular issue by doing this:

```
fixture.Customize<ViewDataDictionary>(c =>
    c.Without(vdd => vdd.ModelMetadata));
```

since ViewDataDictionary.ModelMetadata is a Func of sorts (can't remember exactly which one).

[OOB support for delegates is coming in a future version of AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/workitem/4226).