# Autofixture - fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>() failing test with illegal request exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, testing, asp.net-mvc-5, autofixture

I'm trying to use Autofixture to test my Mvc controller with this code:-

```
 var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
 fixture.Customize<ViewDataDictionary>(vdd => vdd.Without(x => x.ModelMetadata));
 var sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyController>();
```

which throws the following exception

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

After some googling around this seems to be down to using MVc4 and above, and the fix was to change the Customize line to

```
fixture.Customize<ControllerContext>(vdd => vdd.Without(x => x.DisplayMode));
```

Hoever this now throws a new exception

```
A request for an IntPtr was detected. 
This is an unsafe resource that will crash the process if used, so the
request is denied. A common source of IntPtr requests are requests for
delegates such as Func<T> or Action<T>. If this is the case, the expected
workaround is to Customize (Register or Inject) the offending type by
specifying a proper creational strategy.
```

I now seem to be stuck.

Has anyone else come accross this problem and solved it? Or know of a different way to easily fixturize my controller?

Thanks

Comment: You need to customize both the `ViewDataDictionary` _and_ the `ControllerContext`. So basically you need to keep both lines. See these answers for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14989866/26396 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592112/26396

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio As far as I can tell, customizing ought to be enough.

Comment: I've just tried, but I can't reproduce this behaviour with AutoFixture 3.39.0 and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3. How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks for all comments - Mark thank you. Digging down, it turns out I had a nuGet error so even though nuGet was reporting 3.39 - the actual version of Autofixture being used was 2.0 - ripped out and re-installed package to 3.39 - all is good. Thank you

Comment: Of course now with the proper version CreateAnonymous<T> needs to be changed to Create<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was down to my .package file telling me I was using Autofixture 3.39.0, but the test project was actually referencing 2.0.0.

Uninstall the old version and remove from solution and re-add solved the problem.